# Get Process Owner is slow at 100% CPU Usage

Tags: c#, window

I made a small console application to get all processes with a specific name in it and I would like to get the process with the highest CPU Usage.

So far it's working fine. The application is fast to this point when I retrieve the owner of the process with the highest CPU usage. When this specific process needs about 90-100% CPU usage it takes about 2 minutes to retrieve the owner. If there are only "sleeping" processes, its much faster.

Could anyone tell me a better solution than mine? I already tried some other solutions to get the owner (even this one at stackoverflow which is using GetOwner)

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool OpenProcessToken(IntPtr ProcessHandle, uint DesiredAccess, out IntPtr TokenHandle);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Process> listProcesses = Process.GetProcesses().Where(x => x.ProcessName.Contains("MyProcess")).ToList();
        Dictionary<Process, double> dictUsers = new Dictionary<Process, double>();

        foreach(Process process in listProcesses)
        {
            PerformanceCounter counter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", process.ProcessName);
            counter.NextValue();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            dictUsers.Add(process, Math.Round(counter.NextValue() / Environment.ProcessorCount, 1));
        }

        dictUsers = dictUsers.OrderByDescending(key => key.Value).ToDictionary(v => v.Key, x => x.Value);

        if(dictUsers.Count > 0)
        {
            string username = string.Empty;

            Process proc = dictUsers.First().Key;
            username = GetProcessUser(proc);

            Console.WriteLine(username);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No user found");
        }
    }

    private static string GetProcessUser(Process process)
    {
        IntPtr processHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        try
        {
            OpenProcessToken(process.Handle, 8, out processHandle);
            WindowsIdentity wi = new WindowsIdentity(processHandle);
            string user = wi.Name;
            return user;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (processHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                CloseHandle(processHandle);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you think if a process takes 90-100% CPU everything else won't be affected?

Comment: Is the `Thread.Sleep(1000);` necessary?

Comment: I think it is necessary, I just read that the output is more accurate if you do a sleep. Of course everything else is affected at 100% usage but 2 minutes? I am sure there must be a faster solution. Maybe a different language? Just a script?